# Let $n$ objects be placed on a circle. We are supposed to select $k$ objects such that no $2$ of the $k$ objects are placed adjacent to each other

Tags: combinatorics

Let us say $n$ objects are placed in a circular manner. We are supposed to select $k$ objects such that no $2$ of the $k$ objects are placed adjacent to each other in the circle.

This was what I was thinking to actually solve this problem

An alien script has $n$ letters $b_1, \cdots , b_n$.

For some $k < n/2$ assume that all words formed
by any of the k letters (written left to right) are meaningful. These words are called
$k-$words. A $k-$word is considered sacred if:

i) no letter appears twice and,

ii) if a letter $b_i$ appears in the word then the letters $b_{i-1}$ and $b_{i+1}$ do not appear. (Here
$b_{n+1} = b_1$ and $b_0 = b_n$.)

For example, if $n = 7$ and $k = 3$ then $b_1b_3b_6$, $b_3b_1b_6$, $b_2b_4b_6$ are sacred $3-$words. On the
other hand $b_1b_7b_4$, $b_2b_2b_6$ are not sacred.

What is the total number of sacred $k-$words?

But I still have no clue, how to move ahead with my thought. Can someone give me a hint.

Comment: In the beginning you forgot to define $n$. This is not so bad because its meaning is clear. Much worser is the fact that you did not formulated the question and end up with  "we are supposed to select $k$ objects". But what are you looking for: the number of all possible selections or something else?

Answer (score 4):

We count the number of admissible selections of one special and $k-1$ ordinary objects. The special object can be chosen in $n$ ways. When this choice is made we have a linear array of $n-1$ objects left. The selection of the  ordinary objects is a binary word of length $n-1$ having exactly $k-1$ ones. Write these ones with ample space between them and at the ends:
$$-1-1-\ldots-1-1-\ .$$
Then write one zero in each of the $k$ spaces:
$$-01-01-\ldots-01-01\>0-\ .$$
There are still $k$ spaces left, in which we have to write $n-2k$ zeros in an arbitrary way. According to stars and bars this can be done in
$${(n-2k)+(k-1)\choose k-1}={n-k-1\choose k-1}$$
ways. The total number $N$ of admissible selections of all objects then comes to
$$N={n\over k}{n-k-1\choose k-1}\ .$$
We have to divide by $k$ since in reality none of the $k$ chosen objects is specialized. E.g., when $n=5$, $\>k=2$ we obtain $N=5$, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

It is just a stars and bars problem in disguise.
Consider $n$ objects to be placed around the circle. Consider $k$ bars to divide the the circle into $k$ parts.
Let $a_1,a_2, \ldots, a_k$ denote the number of objects between these bars.

Select the starting position of the first bar in $n$ ways.

So we have $a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_k=n-k$, and $a_i \geq 1, \forall 1 \leq i \leq k$ due to the given condition of no two choosen objects being adjacent.

Also as this is a circular permutation, each solution gets repeated by a factor of $k$. For example the tuple solution of $(a_1,a_2,\ldots a_k)$ is identical to any of the $k$ cyclic permutations of $(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_k)$.

Hence the final answer is $\frac{n}{k}{n-k-1 \choose k-1}$.

Comment: If two adjacent parts contain just one object (ie if $a_i=a_{i+1} = 1$ for some $i$) each then when you pick the 2 objects next to the bar you'll be picking adjacent objects

Comment: Its wrong i think. For example pick $n=4$ and $k=2$. The number of ways is of choosing $2$ non adjacent objects is $2$, but your formula gives $1/2$ which is absurd.

Comment: Nice :) Now it works

Answer (score 0):

Actually, once you have chosen the first element to keep, you break the circular thing.

Let's say you have $n$ objects. You have $n$ options for choosing the first object. Once this is done, you need to choose $k-1$ objects from the remaining $n-3$ (eliminating the two neighbors). But in this new case, there are no more circular behavior, just a chain.

For the next object, we have two options : either we choose one end of the chain, or an object in the middle.

There are $2$ choice for an end of the chain (except if there is only one remaining object), and then we recursively go to the same problem with $k-2$ to choose from $n-5$ objects.

If you choose an object in the middle (there are $n-5$ of them), you actually create two sub-instances of the problem : you have to choose $k-2$ between two chains of elements, whose lengths sum up to $n-6$. I would guess that this point is the most tricky one, with several combinatorics involve.

I think that decomposing the problems in sub-routines like this could help to find a recursive formula, given $n$ and $k$, but I have no further clue except for testing for small values and try to find a pattern emerging.

Hope that'll help.